# Removing space from string crashes when checking two string for anagrams to each other

Tags: c++, string

**Double free or corruption is thrown** when checking two string for anagrams to each  other.

My approach for checking anagrams is:

step 1: Remove all the space from Both input string.

step 2: Sort both the string.

step 3: Return false if length differ.

step 4 : Return true if all char matches.

Note

when user input with space it crash.

ex **input 1 : hello world**

**input 2 : hello world**

```
output : *** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000023ca0b0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

For sinlge word its work fine

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>

bool anagrams(std::string usr1,std::string usr2)
{
        if(usr1.length()==usr2.length())
        {

                for(std::string::size_type pos = 0 ; pos<= usr1.length()-1 ; ++pos)
                {
                        if(pos==usr1.size()-1)
                        {
                                if(usr1[pos]==usr2[pos])
                                return true;
                        }

                        if(usr1[pos]==usr2[pos])
                        {
                                continue ;
                        }
                }

        }
        return false;
}

int main()
{
        std::string userInput1;
        std::string userInput2;


        std::getline(std::cin,userInput1);
        std::getline(std::cin,userInput2);

        std::string::iterator end_pos1 = std::remove(userInput1.begin(),userInput1.end(),' ');
        userInput2.erase(end_pos1,userInput1.end());

        std::string::iterator end_pos2 = std::remove(userInput2.begin(),userInput2.end(),' ');
        userInput2.erase(end_pos2,userInput2.end());

        std::sort(userInput1.begin(),userInput1.end());
        std::sort(userInput2.begin(),userInput2.end());

        if(userInput1.empty() || userInput2.empty())
                return 0;
        if(anagrams(userInput1,userInput2))
                std::cout<<"String is anagrams"<<"\n";
        else
                std::cout<<"String  not  anagrams"<<"\n";

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `userInput2.erase(end_pos1,userInput1.end());` You erase twice from `userInput2`.

Comment: yes :-( i am really sorry for bad question please excuse can you please put it as answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're erasing `userInput2` twice. Change the line after your first call to remove, so that it erases `userInput1` instead.